# What does "His brain is as cunning as his fingers" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning

I found the following sentences on Mysteryontilt.tumblr.com. The title is The Sherlock: [The Red-Headed League](http://mysteryontilt.tumblr.com/post/125696781087/the-red-headed-league):

> ... And here is why I think John Clay is an underrated villain.  Here are
>   Peter Jones’s words about him. John Clay, the murderer, thief,
>   smasher, forger.  He’s a young man, Mr. Merryweather, but he is the
>   head of his profession, and I would rather have my bracelets on him
>   than on any criminal in London.  He’s a remarkable man, is young John
>   Clay.
>
> His grandfather was a royal duke, and he himself has been Eton and
>   Oxford.  **His brain is as cunning as fingers**, and though we meet signs
>   of him at every turn, we never know where to find the man himself. 
>   He’ll crack a crib in Scotland one week, and be raising money to build
>   an orphanage in Cornwall the next.  I have been on his track for years
>   and have never set eyes on him yet...

What does the sentence in bold mean? Dees it mean something like he is smart as like his skillful fingers?

Comment: Can you give a little more context, please? Where did you see this phrase?

Comment: It's always possible both conversants know perfectly well that the person they're discussing is exceptionally cack-handed, in which case it's being pointed out that he's *stupid* as well.

Comment: Hi, SuperSaiyantst. I edited your question and please see how it has been edited. Your previous two questions were all closed. Please try to follow the guidelines of this community when [asking a question](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). I will not edit your question like this again. Please note that there is still a chance that your question could be closed for lack of your own research. :-)

Comment: `cunningness(brain)` = `cunningness(fingers)`

Comment: Presumably both Clay's brain and his fingers are quick, nimble, and difficult to anticipate in their workings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a play on two senses of *cunning*.  The first, referring to "brain"  means ingenuity, particularly of a deceitful type.  This particularly true of John Clay, who, although a felon ("murderer, thief, smasher") has managed to escape detection, even going so far as to disguise himself as a philanthropist, a benefactor of orphanages.

The second sense, applying to "fingers" means dexterous and skillful.  We find this use in Psalm 137:

> If I forget you, O Jerusalem, let my right hand forget its **cunning**.

John Clay is a forger and a cracker of cribs (i.e., a housebreaker, possibly by means of picking locks), which means he has steady and skillful fingers for these illegal activities.